# Why do I get MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE?

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I have the following code :

```
        MQQueueManager mqm = null;
        MQQueue mqQueue = null;
        try
        {
            mqm = new MQQueueManager("SWIFTQM", "SWIFTCHANNEL", "localhost");
            mqQueue = mqm.AccessQueue("SWIFTQ", MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
            MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
            MQGetMessageOptions mqGetMsgOpts = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            mqGetMsgOpts.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
            mqQueue.Get(mqMsg, mqGetMsgOpts);
            string s1 = "";
            if (mqMsg.Format.CompareTo(MQC.MQFMT_STRING) == 0)
                s1 = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength);
            string s2 = "";
            mqQueue.Get(mqMsg, mqGetMsgOpts);
            if (mqMsg.Format.CompareTo(MQC.MQFMT_STRING) == 0)
                s2 = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.MessageLength);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mqQueue != null)
                mqQueue.Close();
            if (mqm != null)
                mqm.Disconnect();
            if (mqm != null)
                mqm.Close();
        }
```

Though the queue has many messages, the second mqQueue.Get gets the "MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE" exception. Is there an option I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to do a `mqMsg = new MQMessage();` before making the second `Get` call. The reason for this is `MQMessage` object gets initialized with the incoming message (headers and message body) during the `Get` call. For example the `MessageId` of the incoming message will be set to MQMessage.MessageId property.

As you can notice the second `Get` is being called with `MQMessage` object initialized in the first `Get` call. What this effectively means is that the second Get call is looking for a message with a message id that you have already received in the first get call. But that message had **already** been received in the first get call itself. Hence the second call fails with `MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE` reason code.

Also you are using `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT` option. But there is no `commit` being called in your code. This option is for receiving messages in a local transaction. If you don't intend to receive message under transaction, then you have to remove this option else do a `mqm.Commit`. If a Commit is not called messages will be redelivered when a connection is made again.

Comment: Thanks, I had solved the problem by setting the message match option to MQMO_NONE, but yours sounds more correct. Also I know about the commit, I just omitted that from the code :)